# Send Email the user password, if password Incorrect

Tags: c#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.text");
            username = sr.ReadLine();
            password = sr.ReadLine();
            email = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            if (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");



        }
        catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, please check your email for password, else try again.");
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
```

My Goal is to send the user their password, if the password is entered incorrectly. But however that username must match the email! So, How would I do that?

Comment: Are you asking for help with sending an email. Have you googled: send email C#

Comment: And you are sending the password to the email just because they typed it wrong once? This is not how its normally done. Its usually a seperate function if the user specifically asks for it.

Comment: well, at least `MailMessage` is instantiated. where is the rest of the code? and, the op can do whatever annoying spam crap he wants.

Comment: Not to mention reading information out of text files. Makes no sense.

Comment: unencrypted password and no hashing ???????????    only store the encrypted hash not the password

Answer (score 0):

You would just want to tack on an `else if` statement

```
if (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
else if(textBox1.Text == email)
{
    //Send email
}
```

But my guess is that you're trying to handle this in the `catch` statement, which won't work. Your logic is flawed. The exception you're catching gets thrown when a login file can't be found for the username provided. That means you haven't read anything, and `username`, `eamil`, and `password` don't have a value in the `catch` statement. In this case, your `catch` logic should prompt the user to try a different username. Then the `if-else` logic above will work.

Comment: You can post your own work as the answer here so others can see and learn from it, as well. Or you can mark mine as the answer if it helped you get where you needed to go... :)